# Schwarz–Pick Theorem for Higher-dimensional Hyperbolic Space?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

According to Wikipedia, [Schwarz–Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#:%7E:text=The%20Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick%20theorem%20then,points%20in%20the%20Poincar%C3%A9%20metric.) says that that a holomorphic map of the unit disk into itself decreases the distance of points in the Poincaré metric, which also means that it decreases distances of points for a two-dimensional hyperbolic space under Poincaré disk model.

My question is: Is there an analog of this theorem for three or higher dimensional hyperbolic space, probably under higher-dimensional Poincaré disk model?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126063/discussion-on-question-by-j-l-schwarzpick-theorem-for-higher-dimensional-hyper).

Answer (score 2):

There exists an analogue for holomorphic map from the unit ball in $\bf C^n$ to itself, or even every bounded open set in $\bf C^n$.

In fact every complex manifold $M$ (for instance open set in $C^n$) such that every map $\bf C\to M$ is constant (for instance bonded open set) admit a natural distance called the Kobayashi distance which is decreased by holomorphic maps.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_metric

The Kobayashi distance of the ball in $\bf C^n$ is the natural generalization of the Poincaré metric :its isometry group is $SU(n,1)$.